# How to find all <meta> tags which are NOT in the HTML comment (<!-- -->) from a file?

Tags: php

I am trying to find all `<meta>` tags which are not in the HTML comment (`<!-- -->`) from a file and fetch(extract) the contents by using PHP function - `get_meta_tags`. But there are two problems when using this function:

1. Though the `<meta>` tags are in the comment, like:

   ```
   <!--
   <meta name="title" content="Title name">
   <mata name="keywords" content="keyword 1, keyword 2, keyword 3">
   <meta name="description" content="Hello world!">
   <meta name="author" content="Author name">
   <meta name="copyright" CONTENT="All rights reserved.">
   <meta property="og:title" content="Title name" />
   <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.example.com/img/logo.gif" />
   <meta property="og:description" content="Hello world!" />
   -->
   ```

   , the `get_meta_tags` function still extracts all `<meta>` tags whether they are in the comment or not into an array. But what I need is to extract the `<meta>` tags which are outside the HTML comment(s). That is, I just want the `<meta>` tags that is REALLY AVAILABLE in this page.
2. If the `<meta>` tags have no name, for example, there are some `<meta>` tags which only have “property” or “http-equiv”, like `property="og:title"`, `http-equiv="refresh"`, the `get_meta_tags` function will not extract these `<meta>` tags into the array.

In order to solve these two problems, how can I do? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```
function get_meta_tags2($url)
{
$result = false;

$contents = file_get_contents(str_replace(array('<!--','-->'), '',$url));

if (isset($contents) && is_string($contents))
{
    $title = null;
    $metaTags = null;

    preg_match('/<title>([^>]*)<\/title>/si', $contents, $match );

    if (isset($match) && is_array($match) && count($match) > 0)
    {
        $title = strip_tags($match[1]);
    }

    preg_match_all('/<[\s]*meta[\s]*name="?' . '([^>"]*)"?[\s]*' . 'content="?([^>"]*)"?[\s]*[\/]?[\s]*>/si', $contents, $match);

    if (isset($match) && is_array($match) && count($match) == 3)
    {
        $originals = $match[0];
        $names = $match[1];
        $values = $match[2];

        if (count($originals) == count($names) && count($names) == count($values))
        {
            $metaTags = array();

            for ($i=0, $limiti=count($names); $i < $limiti; $i++)
            {
                $metaTags[$names[$i]] = array (
                    'html' => htmlentities($originals[$i]),
                    'value' => $values[$i]
                );
            }
        }
    }

    $result = array (
        'title' => $title,
        'metaTags' => $metaTags
    );
}

return $result;
}
```

output will be:

```
<?php
Array
(
[title] => Teleit.pl - strony internetowe
[metaTags] => Array
    (
        [description] => Array
            (
                [html] => <meta name="description" content="Java, PHP, and some other technological mumble jumble. Also, some real-life stuff as well." />
                [value] => Java, PHP, and some other technological mumble jumble. Also, some real-life stuff as well.
            )

        [DC.title] => Array
            (
                [html] => <meta name="DC.title" content="Mariano Iglesias - Weblog" />
                [value] => Mariano Iglesias - Weblog
            )

        [ICBM] => Array
            (
                [html] => <meta name="ICBM" content="-34.6017, -58.3956" />
                [value] => -34.6017, -58.3956
            )

        [geo.position] => Array
            (
                [html] => <meta name="geo.position" content="-34.6017;-58.3956" />
                [value] => -34.6017;-58.3956
            )

        [geo.region] => Array
            (
                [html] => <meta name="geo.region" content="AR-BA">
                [value] => AR-BA
            )

        [geo.placename] => Array
            (
                [html] => <meta name="geo.placename" content="Buenos Aires">
                [value] => Buenos Aires
            )

    )

)
?>
```

credits original version:  mariano at cricava dot com, i change this a little for you.